# Gadfly (Julia): how to add text annotation to a plot?

Tags: plot, julia, gadfly

In Stata I can add text to a plot at given coordinates, e.g.:

```
clear

set obs 10

gen x = rnormal()
gen y = rnormal()

twoway scatter y x, text(0.8 0.8 "Some text")
```

The result is "Some text" at coordinates (0.8, 0.8):

[image: Scatter plot with text annotation inside plot]

I want to add a similar annotation in Julia with Gadfly. I found [`Guide.annotation`](http://gadflyjl.org/stable/lib/guides/guide_annotation.html#Guide.annotation-1) that can add layers of graphs and I could not figure out how to apply it to text instead of shapes. The documentation mentions at the top:

> Overlay a plot with an arbitrary [Compose](http://composejl.org/) graphic.

but the `Compose` link shows a website in Chinese.

How can I add a text label (or caption, or annotation) with Gadfly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the [guide on `Compose`](http://giovineitalia.github.io/Compose.jl/latest/index.html#Text-1) in `julia`. In the example in your link they use `Circle`, but you just as easily can use:

```
text(x, y, value)
```

or using the linked example code:

```
Pkg.add.(["Gadfly", "Compose"])
using Gadfly, Compose;
plot(x = rand(10),
     y = rand(10),
     Guide.annotation(compose(context(), text(0.8, 0.8, "Some text"))))
```

in the link I provided they redirect to a source file for the comprehensive list:

> These are basic constructors for the in-built forms - see src/form.jl for more constructors.
>
> - polygon(points)
> - rectangle(x0, y0, width, height)
> - circle(x, y, r)
> - ellipse(x, y, x_radius, y_radius)
> - text(x, y, value)
> - line(points)
> - curve(anchor0, ctrl0, ctrl1, anchor1)
> - bitmap(mime, data, x0, y0, width, height)

Comment: Yes, this works in normal scale: `using Gadfly, Compose; plot(x = rand(10), y = rand(10), Guide.annotation(compose(context(), text(0.8, 0.8, "Some text"))))`. But it fails in log-scale: `using Gadfly, Compose; plot(x = rand(10), y = rand(10), Scale.y_log10, Guide.annotation(compose(context(), text(0.8, 0.8, "Some text"))))`. It looks like a bug. Do you have a workaround?

Comment: @mmorin Can you specify what is is the bug? If it's too complex to work around t may be worth accepting this answer and asking another question on SO about that.

Comment: I posted this [on GitHub](https://github.com/GiovineItalia/Gadfly.jl/issues/1165) and the bug is that "Guide.annotation does not auto-adjust to Scale.y_log10" so the solution is "to use log10(0.8) in text()". Yes, I accepted the answer.

Comment: @mmorin Ahh, I see the bug. Awesome you get a workaround so quickly.